# iPhone AVAudioPlayer failed to find codec

Tags: iphone, avaudioplayer

I am writing an app that downloads a wav file from a server and needs to play that file.  The files use the mulaw codec with 2:1 compression.  These wav files are dynamically created by a seperate process so there is no way for me to preconvert the files to a different format or codec, I need to be able to play them as is.

I am using an AVAudioPlayer instance initialized as follows:

**NSURL *audioURL = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"http://xxx.../file.wav"];

NSData *audioData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:audioURL];**

AVAudioPlayer *audio = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithData:audioData error:nil];

[audio play];


However, when the play method executes, I get the following Console Output when executing on the Simulator:

**AudioQueue codec policy 1: failed to find a codec of the requested type**

I also tried saving the downloaded data to a local file and using a file URL, however that yeilds the same results.  The downloaded file does play fine on both Mac and Windows based desktop media players.

The SDK docs state that the mulaw codec is supported on the iPhone, so I am unsure why it is failing to find it.  Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anthony,

I received the same error message as well while using the Simulator.  **However** I tried it on the device and it worked flawlessly.

For whatever reason, the simulator doesn't have all the codecs the device has (mulaw is software based decoded so the software must differ between the two).

Hope that helps you,

Rob

Comment: Thanks Rob, I'll give it a try on the device.

Answer (score 0):

Well an official thanks to Rob!  This drove me crazy for a while, but in the end it does work fine on the device, just not in the Simulator.